# programing "back-button" in Android

Tags: android, back-button

I programmed "back button" in Android using this code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TabsActivity.class);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

And it works OK. but I have problem with "Log-out" in my app after I program "back button", when user wants to log-out, "TabsActivity.class" opened, then app stopped! 
This code used for log-out user. And it worked good before programming "back button".

```
        ParseUser.logOut();
        finish();
```

Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Do Something Like

Activity

```
 public class youractivity extends Activity {
 /*Your Declaration's here*/
 public int isLoggedIn;

 /*Your Functions here*/
 private loginFunction()
 { 
   parseUser.logIn();
   isLoggedIn=1; 
 }

 private logoutFunction()
 { 
   parseUser.logOut();
   isLoggedIn=0; 
 }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  if(isLoggedIn==1){
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent setIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TabsActivity.class);
    startActivity(setIntent);
      }
  else
  super.onBackPressed();
  }
```

Comment: thanx but it still doesn't work, can I startActivity without "new Intent"; I think the problem with it!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem, Thank you. Just I used this code for logout:

```
        ParseUser.logOut();
        ParseUser.logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstScreenActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Thanx every one ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent setIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TabsActivity.class);
setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);                                 
startActivity(z);
```